# Error in testing react/redux connected components using redux connected components approach

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

Redux highlights an approach for testing connected components here, [writing tests](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components), that I follow but I keep getting this error:

Expected the reducer to be a function.

```
  10 |   {
  11 |     initialState,
> 12 |     store = createStore(communityReducer, initialState),
     |             ^
  13 |     ...renderOptions
  14 |   } = {}
  15 | ) {
```

This is the format of my reducer,

```
const communityReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {   
    switch (action.type) {    ...   } 
}
```

that I import as:

```
import { communityReducer } from "../../reducers/communityReducer";
```

The component I am testing takes this format

```
const CommunityList = (props) => {
  const { getCommunities, communityList } = props;

  ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  authReducer: state.authReducer,
  communityReducer: state.communityReducer,
  communityList: state.communityReducer.communityList,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCommunities })(CommunityList);
```

*getCommunities* is an action

```
import { getCommunities } from "../../actions";
```

that takes this format:

```
export const getCommunities = () => async (dispatch) => {
  ....
};
```

Any idea why I get this error?

Comment: I would check the exports and imports of `communityReducer`.  You are importing it as a named import (not default) but it doesn't appear to have `export` in front of it.

Comment: I export it as a default with `export default communityReducer;` at the end of the file

Comment: Ok then that's your problem!  You need `import communityReducer from "../../reducers/communityReducer";` instead of `import { communityReducer } from "../../reducers/communityReducer";`

Comment: I tried that and I get a different error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'communityList' of undefined

      136 |   communityReducer: state.communityReducer,
    > 137 |   communityList: state.communityReducer.communityList,
          |                                         ^
      138 | });

seems like the reducer is not being recognized at all

Comment: the reducer has communityList as one of the props in the initialState

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  name: "",
  year: null,
  township: "",
  population: null,
  communityList: [],
  currentCommunity: null,
  communityProjects: {
    water: {},
    sanitation: {},
    hygiene: {},
  },
};

and the error now is:

 TypeError: Cannot read property 'communityList' of undefined

Comment: You are accessing the wrong property.  When you call `createStore(communityReducer)` it would be `state.communityList` instead of `state.communityReducer.communityList`.

Comment: If you want it to be `state.communityReducer.communityList` then you need to do `createStore(combineReducers({communityReducer}))`.  Otherwise the communityReducer state is the entire store state.

Comment: this is the example redux provides, 

function render(
  ui,
  {
    initialState,
    store = createStore(reducer, initialState),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions })
}

and all I have do is replace the reducer with my reducer

Comment: I think I got past the reducer issue, thanks @Linda.
But I seem to have a new issue with the action function, here is it's format:
export const getCommunities = () => async (dispatch) => {
    let config = {...};
    await axiosInstance(config)
      .then((res) =>{..})
      .catch((error) {..});
};

The error:
Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
    > 34 |     getCommunities();
         |     ^


much appreciated!

Comment: Here is the store:

const middleware = [thunk];
const persistConfig = {
  storage: localforage
};
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({ trace: false, traceLimit: 25 });

export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

Comment: Your *real* store has thunk middleware.  But the store that you created for your tests does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone has a similar issue, here is what has worked for me:

```
// test-utils.js
import React from "react";
import { render as rtlRender } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
// import your combined reducers here
import rootReducer from "./reducers/index";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";

const thunk = ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next) => (action) => {
  if (typeof action === "function") {
    return action(dispatch, getState);
  }

  return next(action);
};

function render(
  ui,
  {
    initialState,
    store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk)),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions });
}

// re-export everything
export * from "@testing-library/react";
// override render method
export { render };
```

Explanation:

From the issue I posted, `store = createStore(communityReducer, initialState)`, I replace the single reducer with the combined reducers and *initialState* with the thunk middleware, `store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))`.

The middleware used here is a custom function provided by redux [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#middleware), however you can also use thunk imported from "redux-thunk".